# UIWebView iPad/iPhone not displaying login alert

Tags: ios, uiwebview, basic-authentication

When i open the following page on the mobile safari browser https://portal.velti.com, it pops-up an alert requesting login information.

This does not happen when i open this URL from a UIWebView.
It just displays blank.

What's the problem, and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I think I'll recommend getting the user to authenticate before you show the `UIWebView`.

Show two `UITextFields` and then load your `UIWebView` something like this:

```
NSString *URLString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@@https://portal.velti.com", 
                                                               userNameField.text,
                                                               passwordField.text] 
                        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

[webView loadRequest:req];
```

You can also run that `NSURLRequest` before you get to the webView part and double check that the user's credentials are right. If you get a 401 code from the server after submitting the username & password the credentials are incorrect.

Good luck,

Aurum Aquila